makensis compile error #12345: GrowBuf realloc/malloc(543160296) failed
I have a large NSIS installer project which has recently started failing to compile with the following error:
Internal compiler error #12345: GrowBuf realloc/malloc(543160296) failed.
Note: you may have one or two (large) stale temporary file(s) left in your temporary directory (Generally this only happens on Windows 9x).
While this is large installer it is under teh 2 GB limit.  I think the issue is the compiler running out of memory but wanted to see if anyone else has seen this before?
NSIS 3.1
WIN 11
I tried to compile on a second machine to make sure it was nothing local.
I have tried to remove sections of the installer to simplify the project and it did allow me to compile it but I'm trying to understand the root cause.
UPDATE
I was able to get away from this error by making some substantial changes to break a part the installer into smaller pieces.

Yes, sounds like out of memory

@Anders thanks for the reply, I was hoping there was something I had missed so this was an easy fix have to try and find a way to reduce the installer

Are there many files or a big file it fails on?

No large files, there are lots of little files that I'm moving towards pre-compressing them and then just extracting from the installer.
However, it fails before it starts compressing the files.

What happens if you turn off solid compression?

No change with solid compression on or off.
